# New closure on scriptblock

Tags: events, powershell, closures

Consider this code:

```
PS> $timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
PS> $timer.Interval = 1000
PS> $i = 1;
PS> Register-ObjectEvent $timer Elapsed -Action { write-host 'i: ' $i }.GetNewClosure()
PS> $timer.Enabled = 1
i:  1
i:  1
i:  1
 ...
# wait a couple of seconds and change $i
PS> $i = 2
i:  2
i:  2
i:  2
```

I assumed that when I create new closure (`{ write-host 'i: ' $i }.GetNewClosure()`) value of `$i` will be tied to this closure. But not in this case. Afer I change the value, `write-host` takes the new value.

On the other side, this works:

```
PS> $i = 1;
PS> $action = { write-host 'i: ' $i }.GetNewClosure()
PS> &$action
i:  1
PS> $i = 2
PS> &$action
i:  1
```

Why it doesn't work with the `Register-ObjectEvent`?

Comment: It would help if you specified what result you expected and what result you got.

Comment: added outputs so I hope it is clear..

Comment: It looks like a bug to me or at least we should have a way to configure this. I found it already submitted:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/541754/getnewclosure-doesnt-work-on-register-objectevent#

Comment: Yes, I submitted it as a bug, because I haven't found any solution and the behaviour looks strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jobs are executed in a dynamic module; modules have isolated sessionstate, and share access to globals. PowerShell closures only work within the same sessionstate / scope chain. Annoying, yes.

-Oisin

p.s. I say "jobs" because event handlers are effectively local jobs, no different than script being run with start-job (local machine only, implicit, not using -computer localhost)

Comment: Makes sense, accepted. How did you find that info about jobs and event handlers? Other source than Reflector? :)

Comment: No, I don't have source code. Only microsoft staff have that. Event handlers are jobs, because get-job will return them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making assumptions that don't hold. PSH is interpreted, so when a code block is created it just holds the source code. When it is later evaluated any variables it uses will be looked up in the normal PSH way: first in the current scope, and then in each outer scope until a variable with a matching name if found.

When the timer fires its event, it executes the code block and thus looks up `$i`. Which is found in the outer scope with a value of 2.

In the second case, if you just use the code block directly (remove call to `GetNewClosure`) then the second execution gives 2.

Comment: And that's what I want - in the second example I want to get 1, not 2. It works there, but not in the first example.

Comment: GetNewClosure is supposed to change the behavior you mention in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables in that case:

```
PS> $global:i = 1
PS> $timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
PS> $timer.Interval = 1000
PS> Register-ObjectEvent $timer Elapsed -Action { write-host 'i: ' $global:i }.GetNewClosure()
PS> $timer.Enabled = 1
i:  1
i:  1
i:  1

PS> Set-Variable -Name i -Value 2 -Scope Global

i:  2
i:  2
i:  2
```

Source:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12535419/1287856
```