# Extract value from powershell regex matches

Tags: regex, powershell, match, extract

As a part of a buildscript in powershell, I am trying to extract a version number from a string using regular expression. The number is assumed to be in a format xx.yy (eg. 10.6) I need the Integer part (in this example, it would be 10) and the fraction part (example: 6)

I want to have a method that checks that both my patterns exists and thereafter extracts the numbers. (I am very much a novice in powershell, and am trying to avoid using C# functions, but rather powershell itself.)

I tried to do this:

```
$integralPart="A"
$fractionPart="B"

function GetVersion {
    param([string]$strVersion)
    $integralPattern="^[0-9]+(?=\.)" 
    $fractionalPattern="(?<=\.)[0-9]+$"

    #Check if string consists of an integral and fractional part
    If ($strVersion -match $integralPattern -eq $True -and $strVersion -match $fractionalPattern -eq $True)
    {
        $strVersion -match $integralPattern
        $integralPart = $matches[0]

        $strVersion -match $fractionalPattern
        $fractionalPart = $matches[0]
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Host "You did not enter a double with an integer and a fractional part (eg. 10.6)"
        Exit
    }
}

GetVersion (Read-Host 'Enter program version')
Write-Host $integralPart
Write-Host $fractionPart
```

In doing so, I was hoping that $integralPart and $fractionalPart would contain my numbers, at they match the values they should

Can anyone explain how this can be done?

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: The problem is that the variables inside the  function are not the ones you have declared at the top. Use solutions from [powershell setting a global variable from a function where the global variable name is a variable passed to the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535419/powershell-setting-a-global-variable-from-a-function-where-the-global-variable-n)

Comment: Ah, should have checked. $matches[0] actually DOES contains the right values.... but i must still do something wrong, as $integralPart and $fractionPart still end up with the values they were intitialized with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell PS that the variables are from global scope with `$global`:

```
$integralPart="A"
$fractionPart="B"

function GetVersion {
    param([string]$strVersion)
    $integralPattern="^[0-9]+(?=\.)" 
    $fractionalPattern="(?<=\.)[0-9]+$"

    #Check if string consists of an integral and fractional part
    If ($strVersion -match $integralPattern -eq $True -and $strVersion -match $fractionalPattern -eq $True)
    {
        $strVersion -match $integralPattern
        $global:integralPart = $matches[0]   // SEE HERE

        $strVersion -match $fractionalPattern
        $global:fractionPart = $matches[0]   // SEE HERE
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Host "You did not enter a double with an integer and a fractional part (eg. 10.6)"
        Exit
    }
}

GetVersion "10.6"
Write-Host $integralPart
Write-Host $fractionPart
```

Output:

```
True
True
10
6
```

Also, you have a typo: inside the `GetVersion`, you have `$fractionalPart` while the global variable is called `$fractionPart`.

Comment: For things like this I'm a fan of casting the RegEx pattern as a `[RegEx]` type, and then doing a `$global:integralPart = $integralPattern.Matches($strVersion).value` kind of thing. Saves you the extra "True" output.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I see but that would require some more changes with the code, I am not sure OP wants that. BTW, I think you meant `.Match` (not `.Matches`).   @Bo Visfeldt: Does that work all right for you?

Comment: Instead of using globals you could save yourself a lot of future pain by adding the variables as parameters to the function. This also increases the functions reusability.

Comment: Actually, I did mean Matches. The Match method only tells you True/False if it does match. The Matches method actually specifies what the matching substring is instead of doing Match, and then using the `$Matches` automatic variable.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Ok, but it does not have `Value` property. It would be necessary to access the first match using the 0th index.

Comment: I beg to differ. Run `'ab12cd','ef34gh','ij56kl'|%{([regex]"\d{2}").matches($_).value}` and it will successfully extract the two digit number from the three strings provided.